# Ubuntu frame does not detect screen changes

Tags: ubuntu-core, mir

I have a problem.
Im trying to run my apps in ubuntu-core using ubuntu-frame.  But in some cases I have problems with my screens.

My environment is:
A normal PC with ubuntu core 22 and a video card Nvidia 1050ti

My installed snaps:

```
$ snap list
Name                Version                Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core                16-2.60.4              16202  latest/stable  canonical✓  core
core18              20231027               2812   latest/stable  canonical✓  base
core20              20231123               2105   latest/stable  canonical✓  base
core22              20231123               1033   latest/stable  canonical✓  base
mesa-core20         21.2.6                 151    latest/stable  canonical✓  -
nvidia-assemble     3-36-gb8b0680          62     22/stable      xnox        -
nvidia-core22       525.147.05+mesa23.0.4  27     latest/stable  canonical✓  -
pc                  22-0.3                 146    22/stable      canonical✓  gadget
pc-kernel           5.15.0-91.101.1        1540   22/stable      canonical✓  kernel
snapd               2.61.1                 20671  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
ubuntu-frame        121-mir2.15.0          7252   22/stable      canonical✓  -
ubuntu-frame-vnc    52-wayvnc0.6.2-1       289    22/stable      canonical✓  -
```

Im working with two screens and I could add another one at any time.
My video configuration in ubuntu frame is this:

```
$ snap get ubuntu-frame display
layouts:
  default:
    cards:
    - card-id: 0
      DisplayPort-1:
        state: enabled    
        mode: 720x1280@60.1 
        position: [1024, 0]   
        orientation: left 
        scale: 1
        group: 0    
      HDMI-A-1:
        state: disabled    
        mode: 1920x1080@60.0 
        position: [2304, 0]   
        orientation: normal 
        scale: 1
        group: 0    
      DisplayPort-3:
        state: enabled    
        mode: 1024x768@60.0 
        position: [0, 0]   
        orientation: normal 
        scale: 1
        group: 0   
  external:
    cards:
    - card-id: 0
      DisplayPort-1:
        state: enabled    
        mode: 720x1280@60.1  
        position: [1024, 0] 
        orientation: left   
        scale: 1
        group: 0 
      HDMI-A-1:
        state: enabled    
        mode: 1920x1080@60.0 
        position: [2304, 0]   
        orientation: normal 
        scale: 1
        group: 0    
      DisplayPort-3:
       state: enabled    
        mode: 1024x768@60.0 
        position: [0, 0]   
        orientation: normal 
        scale: 1
        group: 0
```

Everyday I use `external` layout.  When I turn on my PC with two monitors its works fine, but if in this moment I connect a new monitor (as a 3rd monitor) this screen does not show anything (only black screen with a blinking underscore). To solve this problem I must restart ubuntu-frame service.

My objetive is connect a 3rd monitor in any moment but avoid to restart ubuntu-frame because if I restart ubuntu-frame it also restarts my running apps too.
I have been testing another way to clear my doubts using ubuntu-server and X11 and I can connect a 3rd monitor and run  xrandr -d :0 --output HDMI-A-1 --mode 1920x1080, after that the monitor shows my apps correctly, it was not neccesary to restart X11 to "update my changes"  (xrand change)

Making another test in ubuntu-core with ubuntu-frame  and using "default" layout I connect 2 monitors, start my PC and its run ok, But when I connect my 3rd monitor and fix the config using `ubuntu-frame set ...` to set my "external" layout and configure this new monitor its doesnt works.
At this point see nothing in the log.

```
$ sudo journalctl -f
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started snap.ubuntu-frame.hook.configure-f77e6582-b63c-47e3-9fd9-0de9fab0f275.scope.
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu systemd[1]: snap.ubuntu-frame.hook.configure-f77e6582-b63c-47e3-9fd9-0de9fab0f275.scope: Deactivated successfully.
```

But, if I restart the ubuntu-frame, of corse restart all my apps (this is a problem for me), I see how to change are applicated in the log.

```
$ sudo journalctl -f
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started snap.ubuntu-frame.hook.configure-f77e6582-b63c-47e3-9fd9-0de9fab0f275.scope.
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.618693] < - debug - > miral: Display config using layout: 'default'
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.618756] <information> miral: Display config:
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: layouts:
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:   default:                        
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:     cards:
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:     - card-id: 0
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:       DisplayPort-1:
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         state: enabled        
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         mode: 720x1280@60.1     
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         position: [1024, 0]       
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         orientation: left     
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         scale: 1
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         group: 0        
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:       HDMI-A-1:
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         state: disabled        
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:       DisplayPort-3:
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         state: enabled        
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         mode: 1024x768@60.0     
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         position: [0, 0]       
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         orientation: normal     
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         scale: 1
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]:         group: 0        
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu systemd[1]: snap.ubuntu-frame.hook.configure-f77e6582-b63c-47e3-9fd9-0de9fab0f275.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: : EGL client APIs: OpenGL_ES OpenGL
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959196] <information> GLRenderer: EGL extensions: EGL_EXT_buffer_age EGL_EXT_client_sync EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import_modifiers EGL_MESA_image_dma_buf_export EGL_EXT_output_base EGL_EXT_output_drm EGL_EXT_protected_content EGL_EXT_stream_consumer_egloutput EGL_EXT_stream_acquire_mode EGL_EXT_sync_reuse EGL_IMG_context_priority EGL_KHR_config_attribs EGL_KHR_create_context_no_error EGL_KHR_context_flush_control EGL_KHR_create_context EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_KHR_partial_update EGL_KHR_swap_buffers_with_damage EGL_KHR_no_config_context EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_3D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_reusable_sync EGL_KHR_stream EGL_KHR_stream_attrib EGL_KHR_stream_consumer_gltexture EGL_KHR_stream_cross_process_fd EGL_KHR_stream_fifo EGL_KHR_stream_producer_eglsurface EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context EGL_KHR_wait_sync EGL_NV_nvrm_fence_sync EGL_NV_quadruple_buffer EGL_NV_stream_consumer_eglimage EGL_NV_stream_cross_display EGL_NV_stream_cross_object EGL_NV_stream_cross_process EGL_NV_stream_cross_system EGL_NV_stream_dma EGL_NV_stream_flush EGL_NV_stream_metadata EGL_NV_stream_remote EGL_NV_stream_reset EGL_NV_stream_socket EGL_NV_stream_socket_inet EGL_NV_stream_socket_unix EGL_NV_stream_sync EGL_NV_stream_fifo_next EGL_NV_stream_fifo_synchronous EGL_NV_stream_consumer_gltexture_yuv EGL_NV_stream_attrib EGL_NV_stream_origin EGL_NV_system_time EGL_NV_output_drm_flip_event EGL_NV_triple_buffer EGL_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge EGL_WL_bind_wayland_display EGL_WL_wayland_eglstream
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959209] <information> GLRenderer: GL renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959214] <information> GLRenderer: GL version: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 525.147.05
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959218] <information> GLRenderer: GLSL version: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959224] <information> GLRenderer: GL extensions: GL_EXT_base_instance GL_EXT_blend_func_extended GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_buffer_storage GL_EXT_clear_texture GL_EXT_clip_control GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_conservative_depth GL_EXT_copy_image GL_EXT_depth_clamp GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_EXT_EGL_image_array GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage GL_EXT_EGL_image_external_wrap_modes GL_EXT_float_blend GL_EXT_frag_depth GL_EXT_geometry_point_size GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_multi_draw_indirect GL_EXT_multisample_compatibility GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2 GL_EXT_multiview_texture_multisample GL_EXT_multiview_timer_query GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_EXT_post_depth_coverage GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_EXT_raster_multisample GL_EXT_render_snorm GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_group_vote GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_EXT_shader_non_constant_global_initializers GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_sparse_texture GL_EXT_sparse_texture2 GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size GL_EXT_tessellation_shader GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_filter_minmax GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_EXT_texture_norm16 GL_EXT_texture_query_lod GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_EXT_texture_view GL_EXT_draw_transform_feedback GL_EXT_unpack_subimage GL_EXT_window_rectangles GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_memory_object GL_EXT_memory_object_fd GL_NV_memory_object_sparse GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile GL_KHR_no_error GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_KHR_robustness GL_EXT_semaphore GL_EXT_semaphore_fd GL_NV_timeline_semaphore GL_KHR_shader_subgroup GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr GL_NV_bgr GL_NV_bindless_texture GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_NVX_blend_equation_advanced_multi_draw_buffers GL_NV_blend_minmax_factor GL_NV_clip_space_w_scaling GL_NV_conditional_render GL_NV_conservative_raster GL_NV_conservative_raster_pre_snap_triangles GL_NV_copy_buffer GL_NV_copy_image GL_NV_draw_buffers GL_NV_draw_instanced GL_NV_draw_texture GL_NV_draw_vulkan_image GL_NV_EGL_stream_consumer_external GL_NV_explicit_attrib_location GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments GL_NV_fill_rectangle GL_NV_fragment_coverage_to_color GL_NV_fragment_shader_interlock GL_NV_framebuffer_blit GL_NV_framebuffer_mixed_samples GL_NV_framebuffer_multisample GL_NV_generate_mipmap_sRGB GL_NV_geometry_shader_passthrough GL_NV_instanced_arrays GL_NV_internalformat_sample_query GL_NV_gpu_shader5 GL_NV_image_formats GL_NV_memory_attachment GL_NV_occlusion_query_samples GL_NV_non_square_matrices GL_NV_pack_subimage GL_NV_packed_float GL_NV_packed_float_linear GL_NV_path_rendering GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object GL_NV_polygon_mode GL_NV_read_buffer GL_NV_read_depth GL_NV_read_depth_stencil GL_NV_read_stencil GL_NV_sample_locations GL_NV_sample_mask_override_coverage GL_NV_shader_atomic_fp16_vector GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation GL_NV_shader_subgroup_partitioned GL_NV_shadow_samplers_array GL_NV_shadow_samplers_cube GL_NV_sRGB_formats GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering GL_NV_texture_array GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_NV_texture_border_clamp GL_NV_texture_compression_latc GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc_update GL_NV_timer_query GL_NV_viewport_array GL_NV_viewport_array2 GL_NV_viewport_swizzle GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_copy_image GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_OES_tessellation_point_size GL_OES_tessellation_shader GL_OES_texture_buffer GL_OES_geometry_point_size GL_OES_geometry_shader GL_OES_gpu_shader5 GL_OES_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_texture_view GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_sample_variables GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_viewport_array GL_OVR_multiview GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959237] <information> GLRenderer: GL max texture size = 32768
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959245] <information> GLRenderer: GL framebuffer bits: RGBA=8880, depth=0, stencil=0
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959305] <information> mirserver: New display configuration:
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959319] <information> mirserver: * Output 1: DisplayPort connected, used
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959326] <information> mirserver: . |_ Physical size 40.2" 890x500mm
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959331] <information> mirserver: . |_ Power is on
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959337] <information> mirserver: . |_ Current mode 720x1280 60.08Hz
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959342] <information> mirserver: . |_ Preferred mode 720x1280 60.08Hz
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959345] <information> mirserver: . |_ Orientation left
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959348] <information> mirserver: . |_ Logical size 1280x720
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959351] <information> mirserver: . |_ Logical position +1024+0
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959355] <information> mirserver: . |_ Scaling factor: 1.00
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959358] <information> mirserver: * Output 2: DisplayPort disconnected
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959361] <information> mirserver: * Output 3: HDMI-A connected, unused
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959364] <information> mirserver: . |_ Physical size 21.7" 480x270mm
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959367] <information> mirserver: . |_ Power is off
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959370] <information> mirserver: * Output 4: DisplayPort connected, used
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959374] <information> mirserver: . |_ Physical size 0.0" 0x0mm
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959377] <information> mirserver: . |_ Power is on
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959380] <information> mirserver: . |_ Current mode 1024x768 60.00Hz
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959383] <information> mirserver: . |_ Preferred mode 1024x768 60.00Hz
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959386] <information> mirserver: . |_ Orientation normal
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959389] <information> mirserver: . |_ Logical size 1024x768
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959393] <information> mirserver: . |_ Logical position +0+0
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959396] <information> mirserver: . |_ Scaling factor: 1.00
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959458] <information> mirserver: New base display configuration:
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959466] <information> mirserver: * Output 1: DisplayPort connected, used
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959470] <information> mirserver: . |_ Physical size 40.2" 890x500mm
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959473] <information> mirserver: . |_ Power is on
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959480] <information> mirserver: . |_ Current mode 720x1280 60.08Hz
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959485] <information> mirserver: . |_ Preferred mode 720x1280 60.08Hz
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959488] <information> mirserver: . |_ Orientation left
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959492] <information> mirserver: . |_ Logical size 1280x720
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959495] <information> mirserver: . |_ Logical position +1024+0
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959498] <information> mirserver: . |_ Scaling factor: 1.00
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959507] <information> mirserver: * Output 2: DisplayPort disconnected
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959511] <information> mirserver: * Output 3: HDMI-A connected, unused
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959514] <information> mirserver: . |_ Physical size 21.7" 480x270mm
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959517] <information> mirserver: . |_ Power is off
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959520] <information> mirserver: * Output 4: DisplayPort connected, used
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959523] <information> mirserver: . |_ Physical size 0.0" 0x0mm
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959526] <information> mirserver: . |_ Power is on
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959529] <information> mirserver: . |_ Current mode 1024x768 60.00Hz
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959532] <information> mirserver: . |_ Preferred mode 1024x768 60.00Hz
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959535] <information> mirserver: . |_ Orientation normal
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959538] <information> mirserver: . |_ Logical size 1024x768
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959541] <information> mirserver: . |_ Logical position +0+0
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959544] <information> mirserver: . |_ Scaling factor: 1.00
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.959550] <information> mirserver: Sending display configuration to session :
Jan 18 09:54:42 ubuntu ubuntu-frame.daemon[14537]: [2024-01-18 09:54:42.964014] < -warning- > mirserver: wl_surface@19 destroyed before associated role
```

And finally, if I now turn off the third monitor (from the button) and want to change the settings again it does nothing and if I turn on the third monitor it still shows the image.